# how to make tableadapter.fill queries parallel

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dataset

Sorry If my google-skills have missed an already existing topic. I searched on the internet for multiple hours and found no answer to this problem...

I am trying to speed up a program based on VB.NET, which is in a private network and talking to clients in europe and the USA with only one SQL Server.
The users of the clients in USA complain about high latency which is totally reasonable since at the moment the program is strictly singlethreaded.

How could I make the queries over the dataset talk to the SQL Server in parallel?

It is not reasonable to query every task in single threads since the latency kills the responsiveness even more if you have to send 5x + queries from Europe to USA back to Europe.

At the moment this program is restricted to VB.NET 4.0 but it will be programmed in the future with the most recent VS2019 pro. If you know any better solution that only works in VS2019 please go ahead :)

```
    Me.DateienTA.Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ProjektConnectionString
    Me.ElementeTA.Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ProjektConnectionString
    Me.AbteilungTA.Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ProjektConnectionString

    Me.DateienTA.Fill(Me.ProjektDS.dateien)
    Me.FirmsTA.Fill(Me.ProjectsDS.Firms)
    Me.AbteilungTA.Fill(Me.ProjektDS.abteilung)
    Me.EmployeesTA.Fill(Me.ProjectsDS.Employees)
    Me.KindOfComponentTA.Fill(Me.ProjectsDS.KindOfComponent)
```

the expected results would be that the program could send all queries at once (in parallel) and hence reduce the ping-times by a factor of parallel processes.

Comment: There's no such thing as VB.NET 4.0.  The very first version of VB.NET was 7.0, as it followed the unmanaged VB6.  Presumably you mean version 4.0 of the .NET Framework, which was introduced with VB 2010 and can still be targeted by VB 2019.  You should probably make use of the Task Parallel Library (TPL) and execute each `Fill` call in a `Task`.  You can then wait on all those tasks, ideally using the `Async`/`Await` pattern, if you're version of VB supports it.  Can't recall what version introduced that but I think that it was later than VB 2010.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but async and await won't work with tableadapter.fill as stated in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129662/using-await-with-a-tableadapter

But thanks to you the solution is just do create your own async methods that create their own threads. Thanks, 
solved as soon as I get VS2019 (how long can it take...*cough*)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use `Task` to run them concurrently. Just make sure each task has its own database connection.

```
Dim t1 As New Task(New Action(Sub() Me.DateienTA.Fill(Me.ProjektDS.dateien)))
t1.Start()

Dim t2 As New Task(New Action(Sub() Me.FirmsTA.Fill(Me.ProjectsDS.Firms)))
t2.Start()

Dim t3 As New Task(New Action(Sub() Me.AbteilungTA.Fill(Me.ProjektDS.abteilung)))
t3.Start()

Dim t4 As New Task(New Action(Sub() Me.EmployeesTA.Fill(Me.ProjectsDS.Employees)))
t4.Start()

Dim t5 As New Task(New Action(Sub() Me.KindOfComponentTA.Fill(Me.ProjectsDS.KindOfComponent)))
t5.Start()

// Wait for all tasks to finish.
Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)
```

Comment: @blah blubb - Thanks for fixing the typo! Next time I will test my answer :-/ Do not forget to accept the answer, this is likely to be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Collect as many of your queries as you can and put them into a Stored Procedure.  Then you will have only one roundtrip (latency) for that set of queries.

This is likely to also help users 'near' to the server, though not as dramatically.